# Anybody got PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig to work with iOS 6 to debug push notifications?

Tags: ios

I've installed PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig onto my device according to

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

but there's nothing displayed in the log. Even if I successfully send an apple push to the handset there's nothing displayed in the console, which there should be according to the tech note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG22

"Note: On iOS 6.x, push logs will not be written to the device console. They are only available by syncing the device with iTunes (r. 12575868)."

...am wondering if you're on iOS6.

-Allan

Comment: I wasn't but that's useful to know anyway.

Comment: Is this applicable for iOS 7 too?